# Unable to retrieve message from TCP/IP server C# console app

Tags: c#, ssl, networking, tcp, networkstream

I have to create a TCP/IP client against a existing server (which has a specific documentation), I followed same but still no response getting from server.
Initially it was the problem of Message format and SMTP Commands, which i replaced from another working command.

I have to use SSL without client certificate for login.

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient("Server DNS", PORT);
Console.WriteLine("-------------------------- \nConnection is : " + client.Connected);
SslStream stream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false, VerifyServerCertificate, null);

stream.AuthenticateAsClient("Server DNS");
Console.Write("Authentication status :" + stream.IsAuthenticated);
// FOR NOW I AM ONLY SENDING LOGIN COMMAND
string line = "BDAT 30 LAST<EOL>{login command}<LF>useridpassword";
stream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(line));
stream.Flush();
string serverMessage = ReadMessage(stream);
Console.WriteLine("\nServer says: {0}", serverMessage);
stream.Close();
```

This sends the command but return message is always empty.
here is method i am using for ReadMessage.

```
static string ReadMessage(SslStream sslStream)
        {
            // Read the  message sent by the client. 
            // The client signals the end of the message using the 
            // "<EOF>" marker.
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
            StringBuilder messageData = new StringBuilder();
            int bytes = -1;
            sslStream.ReadTimeout = 60000;
            do
            {
                // Read the client's test message.
                bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                sslStream.Flush();

                // Use Decoder class to convert from bytes to UTF8 
                // in case a character spans two buffers.
                Decoder decoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
                char[] chars = new char[decoder.GetCharCount(buffer, 0, bytes)];
                decoder.GetChars(buffer, 0, bytes, chars, 0);
                messageData.Append(chars);
                // Check for EOF or an empty message. 
                if (messageData.ToString().IndexOf("<EOF>") != -1)
                {
                    break;
                }
            } while (bytes != 0);

            return messageData.ToString();
        }
```

Below is the screenshot for same code
[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87sZf.png)

[I am also getting this error when use break points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBLGg.png)

---

Sorry for this long post but i think these info was necessary. 
Please any help is appreciated .. Its very frustrating situation as i couldn't proceed since last 8 days bcz of it.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you supposed to send `<LF>` or are you supposed to send the character `\n` which represents a `LF` character.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain , I  have to send the format like : Message id + LF character (hex 0A), this is described in doc.

Comment: @RajatSingh how did you go with this? We are having the same issue, so hopefully, your case may help.